# Using 64bit Windows 2008 in a virtual environment

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have a license for Windows 2008 Server R2 but I wanted to set it up as a virtual server running on another box, but I am having problems installing it due to the fact that it thinks it's a 32 bit operating system because of Virtual PC.

The plan was to create the VHD of the Windows 2008 Server using my desktop and then move it onto the server when it was ready;  My desktop runs Windows 7 64 bit and thought I could install the 64 bit version of Server 2008 but the installation stops me saying that the host environment is 32 bit, where it's not.

Is there a way to do what I want to do?  Different software, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pick another hypervisor, VirtualPC is a bit poor really for this day and age, try something like VMWare Server/Workstation/ESXi or MS's Hyper-V - even a free one like Virtualbox. Oh and another thing, have you checked you've got a 64-bit CPU?

Comment: VirtualBox sounds good - and yes, I do have a 64 bit CPU!

Comment: @Brett: Great! Make sure you have virtualiztion enabled in your BIOS.

Comment: +1 For VirtualBox reference

Answer (score 3):

VirtualPC will only function as a 32-bit environment for the guest OS.